# How do I open a window based on the textContent of a div element after a click event of that div element?

Tags: javascript

Iam using  the switch case in my javascript to open a window after clicking the div element based on its textContent. The div element is embedded in an Aspnet's listview control. The problem when ever I click the div element the switch function takes me to the default part while the alert function actually shows the the
The following is my javascript

```
function select(xx) {
if (xx != null) {
switch (xx.textContent){
case "Stock Receipt":
window.open("ReceipPg.aspx", "DescriptiveWindowName", "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
break;
case "Stock Issues":
Window.open("Issuetoc.aspx", "DescriptiveWindowName", "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
break;
case "Stocktaking Counts":
window.open("StockTak.aspx", "DescriptiveWindowName", "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
break;
default: Alert(xx.textContent)
    }
```

}

my markup

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lvtSelected"
    DataSourceID="srcSubM"
    ItemPlaceholderID="ItemPlaceholderID2"
    OnPreRender="lvtSelected_PreRender"
    runat="server"
    OnItemDataBound="lvtSelected_ItemDataBound">
    <LayoutTemplate>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemPlaceholderID2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </tr>
    </table>
      </LayoutTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
      <td style="background-color:#ccccff; border:solid thin black;">
      <div id="div1" class="a"
      onclick="select(this);"
      onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out(this)"
      style="background-color:#ccccff; 
      border:solid thin black; width:100px;"><%#Eval("MChld") %>
      </div>
      </td></tr>
      </ItemTemplate>

      </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your switch statement to:

```
switch (xx.textContent.trim()){
```

This will eliminate the extra new line you have as a result of the format of your data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is not in your `switch` case but in `xx.textContent`, I made a test case which is working fine.

```
function select(xx) {
    if (xx != null) {
        switch (xx.textContent){
            case "Stock Receipt":
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Stock Receipt"
            break;

            case "Stock Issues":
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Stock Issues"
            break;

            case "Stocktaking Counts":
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Stock Counts"
            break;
            default: alert(xx.textContent);

        }
    }
}

var xx = {textContent : "Stock Receipt"}
select(xx);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5dt9evcv/)

Answer (score 0):

The switch concept is fine, the problem is that your text between the

```
<div> YourTextHere
</div>
```

has a return after it, consequently it doesn't match on the switch. See this for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z8v25vcj/3/

You need to move the `</div>` to after the `<%#Eval("MChld") %>` like this:

```
<%#Eval("MChld") %></div>
```

Or you need to strip trailing returns and white space from xxx.textContent